# ARKit : Translate a 3D Object on camera view

Tags: ios, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I'm actualy developing an AR application on xCode with **ARKit**.

I have my iPad who is on a particular orientation and when I add a SCNode on (0,0,0) to my SCNScene with a ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration it appears in front of the camera when the iPad is perpendicular to the ground like so :
[image: The iPad is perpendicular to the ground and the 3D object is at (0,0,0)]

*The iPad is perpendicular to the ground and the 3D object is at (0,0,0)*

I would like to have **my SCNode to appears directly on the iPad screen when I launch the ARScene** like this :

[image: The iPad is oriented in direction to the flower pot and i had to set the coordinates manually]

*The iPad is oriented in direction to the flower pot and i had to set the coordinates manually*

How can i do that ?
I imagine i would have to do something like a **translation of coordinates** but I don't know how to do that.
And if it can help, i can have the distance between the camera and the flower pot

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the coordinates of the object in a SCNMatrix4 form as follows:

`let translationMatrix = SCNMatrix4Translate(theNode.worldTransform, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1) //tx, ty, tz are translations in each axis i`
and then `theNode.transform = translation matrix`